# Can this code be more simple? Which code looks better? [Reversed Loop]

Tags: python

Can you make code 1) even more simple than it is?

Or maybe there is some better approach?

I wrote this two really simple code just to visualize the differences.

From my perspective, code 1) looks to be more clear then 2), especially when implementing more stuff in loop, for example list of dicts.

1) For with zip

```
shopping_list =['bananas', 'car', 'rum', 'cat', 'meat', 'jelly']
for i, item in zip(range(len(shopping_list)-2, -1, -1), shopping_list):
    print(i, item)
    if item == 'cat':
        shopping_list.pop(i)
```

`print()`

2) just for

```
shopping_list =['bananas', 'car', 'rum', 'cat', 'meat', 'jelly']
for i in range(len(shopping_list)-1, -1, -1):
    print(i, shopping_list[i])
    if shopping_list[i] == 'cat':
        shopping_list.pop(i)
```

Result of loop is:

```
['bananas', 'rum', 'meat', 'jelly']
```

Comment: Both solutions are bad. Use `shopping_list = [word for word in shopping_list if word != 'cat']` instead.

Comment: or `list(filter(lambda x: x != 'cat', shopping_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions are not good, because unecessary complexity and because you modify a list while looping on it (which can be tricky).

Use either [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (as mentioned in comments):

```
shopping_list = [w for w in shopping_list if w != 'cat']
```

Or the `filter` method:

```
shopping_list  = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'cat', shopping_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the original list to remove words which don't satisfy the condition, which you seem to be doing in the first two approaches.

Instead, you can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to remove elements based on the condition `word != 'cat'`

```
shopping_list =['bananas', 'car', 'rum', 'cat', 'meat', 'jelly']
print(list(filter(lambda x: x != 'cat', shopping_list)))
```

The output will be

```
['bananas', 'car', 'rum', 'meat', 'jelly']
```

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzKrug you accepted and then unaccepted my answer, was something missing in my answer ? Let me know and I can address it